# The best way to compare a vector to which a set of vectors representing category

Tags: python, vector, max, distance, mean

Lets say I have vectors representing i.e. 3 categories (a, b, c). Each categories has elements as follows:

```
> a1 = {0, 43, 32, 52, 12}, a2 = {0, 42, 65, 34, 54}, a3 = {2, 23, 65, 45, 34}
> b1 = {89, 23, 54, 65, 75}, b2 = {32, 32, 54, 65, 67}, b3 = {79, 32, 65, 43, 34}
> c1 = {120, 250, 655, 0, 20}, c2 = {133, 305, 560, 4, 39}, c3 = {142, 287, 600, 1, 40}
```

What  I want to do to clasify new data, for example, n = {80, 350, 40, 59, 0} into one of the group. Curently I use two approaches based on mean and max of elements in each group, so that:

```
> a_mean = {0.67, 36 54, 43.67, 33.33}, a_max = {2, 43, 65, 52, 54}
> b_mean = {66.67, 29, 57.67, 57.67, 58.67}, b_max = {89, 32, 65, 65, 75}
> c_mean = {131.67, 280.67, 605, 1.67, 33}, c_max = {142, 305, 655, 4, 40}
```

Basically, when using mean, I calculate the distance of the new data n = {80, 350, 40, 59, 0} to a_mean, b_mean, and c_mean using max mean discrepacy (MMD). The smallest number will be selected. 
Similarly, when using max, I use a_max, b_max, and c_max rather than a_mean, b_mean, and c_mean.

In my real case, I have hundreds vector for each category. When comparing the new data, the result of MMD shows same value, i.e. 0.04, for each category. I believe that there is something wrong with using mean and max approach. For such case, is there any suggestions how to create a reference vector for each category besides using mean and max?

Comment: There is no value which is 0.04 away from 0.67, 66.67 and 131.67 so your max mean discrepancy does not correspond to your example. If you get an impossible value for your example, then you need to fix that rather than asking for a better reference vector.

Comment: hi, 0.04 is just an illustration, for case above the distance between new data to a_mean, b_mean, and c_mean are 0.33822628888270456, 0.435213840355239, 0.3801624494358602 respectively